# (node:2609) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE (ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.7)

Tags: javascript, angular, font-awesome-5

My angular version 
**Angular CLI: 10.0.5

Node: 12.18.3

OS: linux x64**

Angular: 10.0.8

After adding angular-fontawesome by command: `ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.7` 
I got error: 
*Warning: Invalid constructor parameter decorator in /home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js:

function () { return []; }
(node:2609) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE

at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:806:20)

at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:677:19)

at /home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:51:21

at new Promise ()

at Object.exports.sendMessageToMaster (/home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming
/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:46:16)

at /home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/worker.js:104:66

at step (/home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:140:27)

at Object.next (/home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:121:57)

at /home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:75

at new Promise ()

(node:2609) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2609) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:2595) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE

at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:806:20)

at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:677:19)

at /home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:51:21

at new Promise ()

at Object.exports.sendMessageToMaster (/home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming
/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/utils.js:46:16)

at /home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/worker.js:104:66

at step (/home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:140:27)

at Object.throw (/home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:121:57)

at rejected (/home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angularFullStack/movie-rater/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:112:69)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

(node:2595) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:2595) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.*

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm seeing this error all of a sudden in my CI build server